# strange behavior when query executed

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, asynchronous, websocket

I'm using websockets and nodejs 0.10.12  and node-postgre 2.2.0 to send data from server to client.

Server gets an id of an object clicked on the client, and performs a query, based on that id (is an int).

I want to get some textual data for this object, along with the names of some images. Just the names (image01.jpg), not the files.

The structure of the database is like so : There are two tables, `pins` (the objects) and `multi` (stands for multimedia). There is a column in `multi` , named `m_pins` which represents the id of a `pins`. So I can connect what multi belongs to which `pins`. So `multi` 2,3,4,5,6 belong to `pins` 2, if they have 2 in `m_pins` .

With those facts given, please check the code

```
client.connect();var query = client.query('SELECT pins.p_name, type.t_name, era.e_name, controller.c_name, multi.m_name FROM pins,era, type, controller, multi WHERE type.t_id=pins.p_type AND era.e_id=pins.p_era AND controller.c_id=pins.p_controller AND multi.m_pins =pins.p_id AND pins.p_id ='+eoid)//eoid came from client

query.on("row", function (row, result) {result.addRow(row);});

query.on("end", function (result) {
//get all the images, now that query comleted
var mnm=[];
            for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++)
            {mnm.push(result.rows[i].m_name);}

//get other data...we dont need the "for" now, its the first element of every table, since its about just one object

                  var name = result.rows[0].p_name; 
           var ty = result.rows[0].t_name;
           var er = result.rows[0].e_name;
                    var cn = result.rows[0].c_name;



//send to user
connection.send(JSON.stringify({name:name,ty:ty, er:er, cn:cn,mnm:mnm}));

    client.end();
});
```

Looks normal to me. But does not work. In the console I get `Cannot read property 'p_name' of undifined`. Its about this line `var name = result.rows[0].p_name;`

The weird thing is that if I remove everyhting about the `multi` table, works fine.

I tried many alternative syntaxes, but cannot fix it.

Thanks for your patience

Comment: Is that javascript? Your query is inside a multi line string and that is not possible in javascript.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Yes is javascript. By "multi line" you mean this line `SELECT pins.p_name, type.t_name,......` has gaps? In my original code has no gaps, I put the gaps here so its more readable. My mistake. I will remove the gaps.

Comment: @slevin you need to make sure "row" event is absolutely firing before "end" event, otherwise `result.row` just doesn't get populated, and therefore `result.row[0]` evaluates to `undefined`

Comment: @dark_ruby Interesting. I thought it has something to do with the `for` after the `query end`. Because my syntax is like the one the creator of the node-postgre module suggests (see [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Query)). Anyway, can you be a little more specific about the `row firing before end` scenario? How can I implement it?

Comment: @slevin it's the "row" event that populates `result.rows`, so if query returns no rows, event wont be firing. To debug can you `console.log` inside row event - to see if it's even firing, an also `console.log(result.rows.length)` in "end" event to see number of rows returned

Comment: What if anything do you see in the server logs?