# cannot pass javascript values from query to websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I use nodejs 0.10.12 and node-postgre 2.2.0

I created a function with two different queries in it, that they execurte fine and return results.

After the queries execute I want to gather all the results from both queries and send them to the client via websockets.

I cannot pass the values from the queries to the websockets. In the client , when I alert the incoming data I get "undifined".  I though to set the vars as globals, but still nothing

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

This is the code

```
//set all vars as globals, at the start of the doc
 var mnm=[]; var name;

//inside the function

//query 1
client.connect();
var query = client.query('SELECT pins.p_name  FROM pins WHERE  pins.p_id ='+eoid)

query.on("row", function (row, result) {result.addRow(row);});

query.on("end", function (result) {  

    for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++)
    {name = result.rows[0].p_name;}

});

//query 2
var query2 = client.query('SELECT m_name  FROM multi WHERE m_pins ='+eoid)

query2.on("row", function (row, result) {result.addRow(row);});

query2.on("end", function (result) { 
      for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++)
     {mnm.push(result.rows[i].m_name);}
client.end();
});


//so , now gather "name" from the first query and "mnm" from the second and send them to client
connection.send(JSON.stringify({name:name , mnm:mnm}));
```

EDIT
Now I realised that If I execute this code for the first time, client alerts undifined. For the second, alerts the data of the previous object I selected. if I click object1 i get undifined. If I click object 2 I get object1. Please advice

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Moreover, this code is highly vulnerable to SQL Injections.

Comment: @SLaks Hello. I just edited the question. Look, the whole mess started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656706/strange-behavior-when-query-executed). If `pins` has no `m_pins` related to it the whole query fails. So I thought implementing two different queries. Oh, please , there is gotta be another way. I'm a newbie and I'm working on that for a week. Please tell me , there is another way

Comment: @Mathieu'OtaK'Amiot Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing it out. Also, I just edited the question

Comment: @slevin: You need to understand what _asynchronous_ means.  In particular, neither query has finished yet; you need to wait for both of them.  Use promises or the async package.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, can you be a little more specific on "Use promises or the async package" ? What are those? Any links? Thanks

Comment: @SLaks Also, did you see the previous question I mentioned? Why is that happening? Because of async again? I thought it should return name etc. and just the mnm empty, not fail the whole query. Thanks again

Comment: https://github.com/caolan/async http://blog.strongloop.com/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/

Comment: @slevin You can just also make the second query in the "end" event of the first one ;)

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for your time anyway. I did not know about promises. Thanks for making me wiser

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mathieu 'OtaK' Amiot's simple but effective idea , I make the second query in the "end" event of the first one.

So here is the code

```
client.connect();
var query = client.query('SELECT pins.p_name  FROM pins WHERE  pins.p_id ='+eoid)

query.on("row", function (row, result) {result.addRow(row);});

query.on("end", function (result) { 

for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++)
    {name = result.rows[0].p_name;}

       var query2 = client.query('SELECT m_name  FROM multi WHERE m_pins ='+eoid)
       query2.on("row", function (row, result) {result.addRow(row);});
         query2.on("end", function (result) { 
           for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++)
           {mnm.push(result.rows[i].m_name);}
        connection.send(JSON.stringify({name:name , mnm:mnm}));
        client.end();
      });//inner query "on end"

}); //outter query "on end"
```

Thanks Mathieu for the amazing idea. Works fine now.